# Saving multiple text box entries to a single file, C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I save text in richTextBox1 and richTextBox2 into the same file, which could be accessed to use those text entries as strings to make labels?  Is it possible to also save the state of a checkbox along with the text from the richTextBoxes?

Answer (score 4):

You can save whatever you like in the file - you just need to work out what format you want to use. For example, you could use LINQ to XML:

```
var data = new XDocument("uistate",
    new XElement("tb1", richTextBox1.Rtf),
    new XElement("tb2", richTextBox2.Rtf),
    new XElement("cb", checkBox.Checked));
data.Save("uistate.xml");
```

Comment: How would I access this data after it has been stored?  For instance, how would you pull the string from the richTextBox1 XElement for use in a new context?

Comment: @TimSchaeppi: If you've stored it in a file, you'd load it back from the file into an `XDocument`, then use something like: `richTextBox1.Rtf = (string) data.Element("uistate").Element("tb1");` You should read up more on LINQ to XML rather than following this blindly though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will save the values in a texfile

```
  var strFilePathAndName = "anyPathAndFilename"
  using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(strFilePathAndName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
  {
     fs.Close();
  }

  // Create the writer for data.
  using ( var w = new System.IO.StreamWriter(strFilePathAndName, true))
  {
     w.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
     w.Write(richTextBox2.Text);
     w.Write(checkBox1.Checked.toString());
     w.Close();
  }
```

Comment: There is no need to use the `ToString()` methods on values that are already in string form. Also, as per standard practice, the use of `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` should *really* be wrapped in `using` statements.

Comment: @SamuelSlade Thanks for the hints. Edited the code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to also save the state of a checkbox along with the text from the richTextBoxes?" I don't get it, but is that what you want ?

```
richtextBox1.text = IsItPossibleToSaveCheckboxState.Checked.ToString();
```

richTextBox1.text will show the check state like True -or- False